# How can I let it start from row 41?

Tags: excel, count, vba

I was wondering how I can paste it starting from row 41. Thanks in advance.

A. Hoek

```
Sub COPY()

    Dim nextrow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 41

    nextrow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1


    With Sheet1
        .Range("a2").COPY Sheet2.Range("A" & nextrow)
        .Range("b2").COPY Sheet2.Range("B" & nextrow)
        .Range("C2").COPY Sheet2.Range("C" & nextrow)
        .Range("d2").COPY Sheet2.Range("D" & nextrow)
        .Range("e2").COPY Sheet2.Range("E" & nextrow)
        .Range("f2").COPY Sheet2.Range("F" & nextrow)
        .Range("g2").COPY Sheet2.Range("G" & nextrow)
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand your question...

Comment: Sorry if question isn't clear. When the macro starts, it will copy the values to Sheet2 (row A2,B2 etc .. ). But i want it to copy it to A41, B41 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub COPY()
    Dim nextrow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 41
    nextrow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With Sheet1
        .Range("a" & i).COPY Sheet2.Range("A" & nextrow)
        .Range("b" & i).COPY Sheet2.Range("B" & nextrow)
        .Range("C" & i).COPY Sheet2.Range("C" & nextrow)
        .Range("d" & i).COPY Sheet2.Range("D" & nextrow)
        .Range("e" & i).COPY Sheet2.Range("E" & nextrow)
        .Range("f" & i).COPY Sheet2.Range("F" & nextrow)
        .Range("g" & i).COPY Sheet2.Range("G" & nextrow)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You mean like this?

```
Sub COPY()

    Dim nextrow As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 41

    nextrow = WorksheetFunction.Max(i, Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    Sheet1.Range("a2:g2").COPY Sheet2.Cells(nextrow, "A")

End Sub
```